# problem with xml document in java

Tags: java, xml

i am writnig a simple program that get a string and translate that to a xml document but it dont show value of content i set it show null!

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


    public class Server {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Server server=new Server();
            Document dc=server.stringToDocument("f0");
            System.out.println(dc.getTextContent());

        }
        public org.w3c.dom.Document stringToDocument(String order)
        {
            org.w3c.dom.Document result=null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try{
            DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            result=db.newDocument();
            Element el=result.createElement("ORDER");
            el.setTextContent(order);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("DB in line 1418 exception");
            }



            return result;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getTextContent` on a document node. This always results in a null value as you can read in the api docs:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()

You will get the value if you call `dc.getFirstChild().getTextContent()` (after appending the element to the document), because now you are calling `getTextContent` on an element node.

Comment: i do that and it works now..thanks alot..i accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the element to the document in order for it to be associated with the document.  Try adding the line:

```
result.appendChild(el);
```

See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10769/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild_org_w3c_dom_Node_) for more information.

Comment: i do that but no change accures..other ideaaaa?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the line:

```
result.appendChild(el);
```

to the stringToDocument method.

To get the xml string to print you can use the following method:

```
public String documentToString(Document doc) {
    try {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        return xmlString;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```